# Scraping data through API after actions with buttons

Tags: python, api, selenium

I wanna grab data from https response, but they data appears only after clicking on the button with opens the dialog window (look at the screen bellow), so I have to open all necessary windows and then run request.get.
The main difficulty is I don't understand how to make request.get for the same window where I run driver.get command.

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
XPATH = "//*[name()='svg' and contains(@class, 'jss350')]"
XPATH2 = '/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[3]/button/span[1]'

# Wait for all svg elements to be clickable
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, XPATH)))

# find list of svg elements
svg_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(XPATH)

for element in svg_elements[3:4]:
    element.click() #open windows
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, XPATH2))).click() #close

#here is I want to run the request.get function to grab data from the same window

driver.quit()

params = {
    'products': 'RU',
}


url = 'my url'

r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers={
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36'})
json_data = r.json()
print(r.url)
print(r.text)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the api's can work independent of UI actions(selenium automated).which means you can pass the necessary data in POST or Get and the api response is available. So there is no need to open a specific window/dialog box, you may try just passing the api data in a POSTMAN client/also in your code.

Comment: Thanx, it was a newly question )